# How to do ahead-of-time (AOT) translation in AngularJS like in Angular 2+?

Tags: angularjs, gulp, gettext, angular-translate, angular-i18n

I have AngularJS version 1.5 and want to translate my web into several foreign languages. The translation will run on different domains and there will be no language change option (no countries flags etc.).

There are many examples for AngularJS - but only for something like ng2 JIT (just-in-time):
https://technpol.wordpress.com/2013/11/02/adding-translation-using-angular-translate-to-an-angularjs-app/
or
https://angular-gettext.rocketeer.be/dev-guide/compile/

Translations are done in browser at runtime.

But I want to something like ng2 AOT (ahead-of-time):
[https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#!#*ahead-of-time*-aot-vs-*just-in-time*-jit-](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#!#_ahead-of-time_-aot-vs-_just-in-time_-jit-)

... compile translations at build time into html/js so no additional javascript library is needed to process translations.

Is there some utility to do that? Gulp task or something?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be best to just hard code the entire site into the different languages you want. We tried to do something similar on our site and realized that it's best to just hard code, Yes, i know that's a lot of work, but it's what works best and 100% comprehensible for each language.